Is $E_{f_0}(f_0(X))\ge E_{f_0}(f(X))$ true?
Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f_0$. Let $f$ be another probability density function.
By Jensen's Inequality, we know that $E \log(f_0(X))\ge E\log(f(X))$. However, I wonder if $E f_0(X)\ge E (f(X))$ is also correct? I feel the statement is wrong but I cannot give a counterexample or proof.

Is $f_0$ the CDF or the PDF of $X,$?

@Leon I took the liberty of making an edit to your question (currently awaiting approval), since the question had been closed with a request for clarification.

The property you ask about does indeed fail. The easiest intuition might be a discrete case. Let $X$ have probability mass function $p$ with $p(0)=1/3$, $p(1)=2/3$. For mass functions $q$, the quantity $E q(X)$ is maximised not by taking $q=p$, but by taking $q(1)=1$. Similarly, in the continuous case, if you take $f_0(x)=1/3$ for $0\le x < 1/2$ and $f_0(x)=2/3$ for $1/2\le x\le 1$, then to maximise $E f(X)$ over density functions $f$ you will take $f$ concentrated on the interval $[1/2, 1]$, e.g. $f(x)=2$ for $1/2\le x\le 1$.

@JamesMartin Correct. I just noticed my error.

I think the question is a perfectly decent one and should be reopened.

@JamesMartin It is on of those unmotivated lets-eat-some-popcorn-and-watch-others-struggling questions.

@KurtG I think you are being far too uncharitable for some reason. The first part seems to be a completely reasonable motivation of the second part. The poster has noticed a property and wondered whether something related is true, and does not know. This is good mathematical curiosity. I would be pleased for my students to follow such lines of enquiry.

@JamesMartin Thanks for your help and kindness! I did try with several distributions but fail to find such an easy counter example, kind of misled by the Cauchy inequality. I'll try harder next time. Your students are lucky to have a teacher like you~

My answer was deleted, for reasons I don't know....  Copy it here for some comment:
Take $f_0(x)=2xI(0<x<1)$ and $f(x)=3x^2I(0<x<1)$ as a counter example.
